# Working of NSMutableData

Tags: nsmutabledata

I am new to ios development.  Please tell me what is NSMutableData and How it works?  I have been searching for this question but have not got any perfect answer.

Answer (score 3):

NSMutableData (and its superclass NSData) provide data objects, object-oriented wrappers for byte buffers. Data objects let simple allocated buffers (that is, data with no embedded pointers) take on the behavior of Foundation objects. They are typically used for data storage and are also useful in Distributed Objects applications, where data contained in data objects can be copied or moved between applications. NSData creates static data objects, and NSMutableData creates dynamic data objects. You can easily convert one type of data object to the other with the initializer that takes an NSData object or an NSMutableData object as an argument.

It inherits from
NSobject -> NSData -> NSMutableData

Comment: Thank you..it helped me a bit more to get it cleared.

Comment: Your most  welcome, if you having any  problem then refer apple developer website for any topic and issues it might also help you